# Google Finance fetch DATE of high and low

Tags: google-finance

I am trying to fetch the **dates** of the high/low of the last 11 days using the following formula `=TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:BAJFINANCE", "high", today()-11,today(),"DAILY"), 2, 0), 2,1))`

`=(TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:BAJFINANCE", "low", TODAY()-11,TODAY(),"DAILY"), 2, 0), 2,1)))`
What is fetches is 8/13/2022 for both while the correct date is 09/14/2022 for High and 9/7/2022 for low.

Where exactly am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I see the Google Finance syntax, I see that startDate should come before the end date:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [end_date|num_days], [interval])
```

See: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

Try it this way: (notice the sequence of `today()-11`)

```
=TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:BAJFINANCE", "high", today()-11,today(),"DAILY"), 2, 0), 2,1))
```

Also, please watch out that Google Finance may not be showing you values with the NSE's actual close prices, but rather the close of the previous day:
***Dates passed into GOOGLEFINANCE are treated as noon UTC time. Exchanges that close before that time may be shifted by a day.***

EDIT:

Your SORT and INDEX parameters need to be changed in order to get the correct result. Use the below:

Low:

```
=(TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:BAJFINANCE", "low", TODAY()-11,TODAY(),"DAILY"), 2, 1), 1,1)))
```

High:

```
=(TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:BAJFINANCE", "high", TODAY()-11,TODAY(),"DAILY"), 2, 0), 2,1)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried your method Sangam, however it doesn't work correctly. I have updated the code for the low too. Both dates give the date of 9/13/2022, which is incorrect.

Comment: I would suggest to test the individual components; i.e. just run GOOGLEFINANCE first and see if these results are correct. Then you can go into the other funcs.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the issue with the params you are passing to your functions